# What is the minimum number of given sets of information required to complete an ICE chart for an equilibrium reaction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, concentration

I'm considering creating a program that automatically completes an ICE chart/table when the minimum given information is provided. The reason I'm posting my question here is because I need to know the possible cases of minimum information required before I can even start the program.

I know you can complete the table if you're given these following sets of information:

- K and initial concentrations
- K and final concentrations
- K and initial concentrations of reactants and final concentrations of products

I also believe there are a ton more, but I'm not sure how to complete the list.

Comment: I'm not thinking about Ksp and Ka. Only just Keq.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I think you have the basics down, first of all I have a couple pointers for you since I have done many (*many*) RICE charts. What I would do if I were you? Since I have some experience in programming I would just use molarities of the initial and final.

You must make the user input the data, say if the user was given moles then make him/her convert it to molarity.

I think you have it pretty much down, you need either the initial concentrations and K or find the K through using the initial concentrations of the products and reactants or find the initial using the product and K.

I mean then again I would work through making this first part down because those are the essentials (atleast what I've learned) and then work on making updates to that program.

Since I do have programming experience I would just use if statements to do the entire thing. `If this is available then solve for this.`

Don't worry about the entire thing yet. Otherwise I would have to say you have pretty much everything down.

**NOTE**: This is not about Ka, Ksp, Kb, just for Keq. Because then you would have to work with the pH and pOH more equations.